# StartsWith string.empty in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to apply filtration with `StartsWith`. The value may be empty. How to get all records if the search string is empty.

```
public void UserFunction (string s_SearchString)
{
    var _List = database.TableName(from c in database.TableNames where c.Name.StartsWith(s_SearchString));
    // other code...
}
```

Here, `_List` will be used in the code ahead. `s_SearchString` may be empty, when it's empty, I want all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the condition in case `SearchString` parameter has a value:

```
var query=database.TableNames;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a_SearchString))
{
  query=query.Where(e=>e.Name.StartsWith(s_SearchString))  
}
var _List = database.TableName(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var db = database.TableName.ToList()
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s_SearchString)) // can also use string method String.IsNullOrEmpty.. your preference
{
    return db.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(s_SearchString)).ToList(); // using lambda expression
}
else
{
    return db;  // s_SearchString is Null or White Space so return all records
}
```

Comment: `ToList()` will load the entire table from database.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a_SearchString))
{
  database.TableNames=database.TableNames.Where(e=>e.Name.StartsWith(s_SearchString))  
}
//other code;
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, it would benefit from an explanation.